# Прокрутить страницу не на 100px а на 100vh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Приветствую.

**Вопрос:**
Как сделать кнопку, которая прокрутит страницу не на определенное количество пикселей, а на **100vh** что равно 100% высоты окна.

Если у блока высота будет 100vh, то он будет растянут на всю высоту блока, какая бы там высота не была.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно повесить обработчик событий на button(к примеру). Чтобы при нажатии кнопки, экран прокрутил страницу на высоту страницы, можно написать функцию, где будет:

```
window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
```

Сама кнопка, примерно так:

```html
<button onclick = 'window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)'>window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.Осталось только сделать так, чтобы плавная прокрутка была.

Answer (score 2):

Используя jQuery с плавной прокруткой:

```js
$("#scroll").click(function() {
  $('body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + window.innerHeight }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.area {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="scroll">scroll</button>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
```

`+=` требуется для относительного скроллинга.